# How to order in descending order of two variables in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have written query like this

```
@data = Data.where(value: params[:value]]).order(created_at: desc)
data1 = Result.where(value: params[:value]]).order(created_at: desc)
if data1?present  
  @data << data1
end
```

Now I want to have @data and data1 values to be sorted in descending order of updated_at?

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Why did you order by `created_at`, if you want to immediately reorder by `updated_at`? Is the second ordering only supposed to occur on conflict, for a 'tie-breaker'?

Comment: unless `desc` is a variable you've defined, you will want `order(created_at: :desc)`

Answer (score 0):

As you fetch from two different tables you can't do the sorting on database level (at least it's not trivial). I suggest you use `sort_by`

```rb
@data = Data.where(value: params[:value]]).order(created_at: desc) + 
  Result.where(value: params[:value]]).order(created_at: desc)

@data.sort_by {|element| -element.updated_at }
```

Please also note that you need to use `+` and not `<<`.

Maybe also have a look at kaminari (https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari).

https://www.rubyguides.com/2017/07/ruby-sort/

Answer (score 0):

For descending order

```
@data = (Data.where(value: params[:value]]).order(created_at: desc) + Result.where(value: params[:value]]).order(created_at: desc)).sort_by(&:updated_at).reverse
```

For ascending order

```
@data = (Data.where(value: params[:value]]).order(created_at: desc) + Result.where(value: params[:value]]).order(created_at: desc)).sort_by(&:updated_at)
```